# Solr integer range query, what fieldType to use?

Tags: solr, cassandra

I am new to solr and trying range query "TO". However I am not able to understand the correct behavior.

Below is my field in table:

```
 order_range int
```

schema.xml contains:

```
<fieldType name="int" class="solr.IntField"/>
```

and

```
<field name="order_range" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

However when I issue, following query

```
 order_range:[20 TO *]
```

it returns the documents where order_range is less than 20.
As per solrwiki,

```
field:[100 TO *] finds all field values greater than or equal to 100
```

Can somebody help me with what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numeric range queries, I would suggest using one of following two field types:

```
<fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

As per documentation in schema.xml:

> For faster range queries, consider the tint/tfloat/tlong/tdouble types.

When you use int field type, it sorts them by lexicographic order.

More detail: http://www.slideshare.net/VadimKirilchuk/numeric-rangequeries